# postgresql with function wrap sql so slow?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance, stored-functions

first sql explain analyse:

```
explain  analyse  select * from ttq.ttq_post;
Seq Scan on ttq_post  (cost=10000000000.00..10000000014.71 rows=171 width=547) (actual time=0.005..0.027 rows=176 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.033 ms
Execution Time: 0.041 ms
```

but if use function wrap the same sql
eg:

```
create or replace function ttq.test_fn_slow() 
  returns  setof ttq.ttq_post 
  language  sql 
  stable 
as $$
select * from ttq.ttq_post;
$$
```

and exec blow function:

```
explain  analyse  select ttq.test_fn_slow();
```

result:

```
ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.27 rows=1000 width=32) (actual time=0.063..0.175 rows=176 loops=1)
  ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.013 ms
Execution Time: 0.192 ms
```

why use function wrap so slow?

try use "immutable" replace "stable" but the result is same!

Comment: I'd say the difference is random. Try both several times and check if you can really observe a persistent significant performance difference. It may alsi be good to test with bigger tables.

Comment: thx yours answer, and  i exec this command some times ,the result no difference  the first sql cost time about 0.040ms,the function cost time about 0.19ms. same sql ,why cost time is difference?

Comment: Is it the same if you run `SELECT * FROM ttq.test_fn_slow();`?

Comment: if exec SELECT * FROM ttq.test_fn_slow(); cost time same as single sql ( select * from ttq.ttq_post) !!

Comment: select * from functionName()  and select functionName() has some  difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional cost must be due to the fact that you are using the set returning function in the `SELECT` clause rather than in the `FROM` clause.

Note that the processing of set returning functions in the `SELECT` clause changed in PostgreSQL v10, so your version may have an influence on this behavior.

Comment: thx your answer,if i want return a select result how write the function ?

Comment: only select propName from functionName() ?

Comment: Yes. I believe you'll have to add a table alias to the function.